# UINavigationBar disappearing on presentViewController:animated:completion

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've been beating my head against a wall for the better part of a week trying to figure out what's going on with this error, but I cannot figure anything out. I've read through all of the view controller documents on Apple's developer stuff, looked through countless articles here, etc.

I've got 3 view controllers: a base view controller, an image editing controller (allows user to zoom in/pan through an image, and on pressing okay, save the image within bounds, return image to the base view via a delegate method, and push it to the last view controller), and finally a BigPictureViewController where the user interacts with the image he saved.

On calling presentViewController:animated:completion from the base view controller, the navigation bar appears for a split second, then disappears. I've completely gutted the final view controller so that it just displays a blank screen identical to when you first create a view controller, but the navbar still disappears, so I know it's not something in the view controller's coding.

Here's the delegate from the image editing controller (contained in the base view controller):

```
#pragma mark - camera view delegate
-(void)cameraView:(CameraViewController *)camView didReturnWithEditedImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    theImage = image;
    BPVCFlag = YES;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Next, in the base view controller's viewWillAppear method, I check for the flag to toggle the segue:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (BPVCFlag)
    {
        BPVCFlag = NO;
        BigPictureViewController *bpvc = [[BigPictureViewController alloc] init];
        UIStoryboardSegue *seg = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"pushitrealgood" source:self destination:bpvc];
        [self prepareForSegue:seg sender:self];
    }
}
```

Lastly, the prepareForSegue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *id = [segue identifier];
    if ([id hasPrefix:@"pushit"]){
        BigPictureViewController *bpvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        bpvc.imageFromLibrary = theImage;
        [self presentViewController:bpvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I've tried presenting it from self.navigationController, etc., and I can get it to stick with a different navigation controller if I use

```
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bpvc];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but that seems like an extremely hacky way to do it, and doesn't actually solve the problem, just circumvents it.

Sorry for the wall of text, but I'd rather be thorough than leave people in the dark.

TL;DR on presentViewController, the navigation bar pops up for a split second and then disappears~

Thanks in advance for any help/tips!

Comment: You're presenting a BigPictureViewController - is it a subclass of UINavigationController?

Comment: self.navigationController is only refer, is controller object init before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "hacky" solution is actually the correct solution. When you call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, the nav controller of the presenting view controller will no longer be visible. You are adding a new layer so to speak.

If you want the presented view controller (your `BigPictureViewController`) to be in a nav controller, you must create a new nav controller passing the new view controller as the root controller. Then you present the nav controller.

So you want this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString *id = [segue identifier];
    if ([id hasPrefix:@"pushit"]) {
        BigPictureViewController *bpvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bpvc];
        bpvc.imageFromLibrary = theImage;
        [self presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! It just felt like a really weird way to get around the problem, but if that's the correct way, then I'll put my mind at ease. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
BigPictureViewController *bpvc = segue.destinationViewController;
bpvc.imageFromLibrary = theImage;
UINavigationController *navcont = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:bpvc];
[self presentModalViewController:navcont animated:YES];
```